# How can you correctly require a module in mocha.opts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using [mocha-mongoose](https://github.com/elliotf/mocha-mongoose) to automatically clear mongo in between tests. In the documentation it says to require the module in your spec file or globally in your spec helper.

Doing it per spec works great, but I want to do it from mocha.opts to keep my code DRY.

*Requiring it with mocha.opts doesn't work. Mongo is not cleared in between specs*

mocha.opts:

```
--require ./test/common.js
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
--recursive
--colors
--timeout 60000
--slow 300
```

common.js:

```
require('mocha-mongoose')('mongodb://your-mongodb-url-here');
```

*Requiring it in each spec file works*

test.js

```
var should = require('chai').should()
  , require('mocha-mongoose')('mongodb://your-mongodb-url-here');

describe("Example test", function() {
    it(' Mongo will be automatically clear all collections',);
});
```

How can I correctly require `mocha-mongoose` in mocha.opts so I don't have to repeat it in every test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works is by checking for `beforeEach` and registering itself as a `beforeEach` hook. Here is the [relevant source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elliotf/mocha-mongoose/637f7fabd9ac4134348e4e7e3e4e384d69db9476/index.js):

```
if (!options.noClear && !beforeEachRegistered) {
  if ('function' == typeof beforeEach && beforeEach.length > 0) {
    // we're in a test suite that hopefully supports async operations
    beforeEach(clearDB);
    beforeEachRegistered = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is that `beforeEach` is not available to modules loaded by `--require`. So you cannot do it with `--require`.

The only thing I can imagine the author of `mocha-mongoose` to mean with "your spec helper" would be a module that contains a bunch of utility functions that each spec requires: instead of adding `require('mocha-mongoose')(...);` to each spec, you'd add it just once to the module that is required by each spec.

Comment: That is exactly what the author of mocha-mongoose (me) meant!